# Lubuntu MinGW undefined references [missing GL libraries?]

Tags: c++, mingw

Trying to compile a third party library on MinGW in Code::Blocks on Lubuntu, and despite my absolute best efforts to eliminate the following undefined references which I've spent ages on, nothing is fixing the issues:

```
undefined reference to `_sfwgl_ext_EXT_swap_control
undefined reference to `_sfwgl_ext_ARB_pixel_format
undefined reference to `_sf_ptrc_wglChoosePixelFormatARB
undefined reference to `_sf_ptrc_wglGetPixelFormatAttribivARB
undefined reference to `_sfwgl_ext_ARB_multisample
undefined reference to `_sf_ptrc_wglGetPixelFormatAttribivARB
undefined reference to `_sfwgl_ext_ARB_pixel_format
undefined reference to `_sfwgl_ext_ARB_create_context
undefined reference to `_sfwgl_ext_ARB_create_context_profile
undefined reference to `_sf_ptrc_wglCreateContextAttribsARB
undefined reference to `_sf_ptrc_wglCreateContextAttribsARB
undefined reference to `_sf_ptrc_wglGetPixelFormatAttribivARB
undefined reference to `_sfwgl_ext_ARB_multisample
undefined reference to `_sf_ptrc_wglGetPixelFormatAttribivARB
undefined reference to `_sfwgl_LoadFunctions
```

From what I can tell is it's possibly some sort of missing GL library or graphics library, however I already have opengl32, gdi32, glu32, glut32 and gle added to the link library which has left the following undefined references untouched.

How do I fix the above errors?

[If it is a missing library or libraries, could I be linked to the download page for the appropriate headers and .a files for MinGW on linux? Thanks.]

Comment: If anyone wants additional details, feel free to ask in the comments.